# How to restrict view of posts to the author only

Tags: web2py

I tried a Reddit app where one can view posts and comments.
My trouble is getting the user t be the only one to view the Posts instead of public view(all postS seen by everyone)
How do I limit that?
I tried:

```
@auth.requires_signature()
def view_posts_by_author():
    ...code
    return locals()
```

but this does not help

Rgards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could code the posts query so it only returns records authored by the current logged in user. Assuming the posts table includes an `author` field that is a reference to the `auth_user` table, you could do something like this:

```
@auth.requires_login()
def view_posts_by_author():
    posts = db(db.post.author == auth.user_id).select()
    return dict(posts=posts)
```

This assumes you have a `post` table something like:

```
db.define_table('post',
                Field('author', 'reference auth_user'),
                ...)
```

Comment: What if you have several fields? db()(db. post. ALL == auth.user_id) does not work

Comment: It's not clear what the intention of that query would be. If the `db.post.author` field is a reference field linking to the `db.auth_user` table, then to restrict the set of records to the logged in user, you would simply ensure `db.post.author == auth.user_id`. It does not make any sense to equate any of the other fields to the value of `auth.user_id`.

Comment: Noted. I was just revisiting my workings. Am having challenges with the restrictions but let me work them up first before I come for help. Still learning web2py, you know